# Where are all the google search results?

Tags: google-search

So its a common thing I see everyday. When I do a google search , it shows millions of results being found. But as and when I keep exploring the following pages. All the results are just over in like 13-18 pages (~200 search results).

So why is it so that the first page shows such a huge number of millions but then all I get is 200-300 results.

And is there some way to view the remaining results.

Comment: Because what you see are just guesses.

Comment: @harrymc What do you mean by this, I'm just curious

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of the page, google will ask you to view the omitted results, you might have to be at the last page to see this message, but just click **Repeat the search with the omitted results included**:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot mully, I know its pretty basic. Thanks for taking out time to help me out.

Comment: It's not a complete solution, because you still won't get millions of results shown on the page, and it's because of what @harrymc said "Google doesn't fully evaluate the query", but it does show more results than before, so its a step forward :)

Comment: Hi mully , yes you are right. even with showing up of omitted results.. I could reach upto 300 results out of 1,12,000 results. Is there something else I can do index the remaining pages.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Google doesn't fully evaluate the query, only enough to show the first page.

The displayed number of results is just a statistical guess, and may be
very wrong.

Comment: ok so what you mean , the huge number it shows on the first page of google search can be a superficial number. the real number is the one that we come across while moving forward with the pages  . Thanks